# How to install CKEditor plugin in Django

Tags: python, django, ckeditor, django-ckeditor

I'm trying to install a plugin for Image uploader for django-CKEditor. However, the buttons do not appear in the CKeditor widget.

The steps that I've use for installing CKEditor plugin is as follows:

1. Download and extract the Image Uploader and Browser for CKEditor plugin.
2. Copy the extracted files to the static folder of CKeditor, i.e. /project/static/ckeditor/ckeditor/plugins/imageuploader. Also tried using the manage.py collectstatic
3. Configure the settings.py file as below.

   ```
   CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
       'default': {
           'toolbar': [
               [      'Undo', 'Redo',
                 '-', 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline',
                 '-', 'Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor',
                 '-', 'Format',
                 '-', 'SpellChecker', 'Scayt',
                 '-', 'Maximize',
               ],
           ],
           'width': 840,
           'height': 300,
           'toolbarCanCollapse': False,
       },

       'simple_toolbar': {
           'toolbar': [['imageuploader',],],
           'width': 840,
           'height': 300,
           'removePlugins': 'stylesheetparser',
           'extraPlugins': 'imageuploader',
       },

   }
   ```
4. Configure the widget as below.

   ```
   class Form(forms.ModelForm):
       description=forms.CharField(widget=CKEditorWidget(config_name='simple_toolbar'
   ))
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In You Model:

```
class YouModel(models.Model)
    text = HTMLField(configuration='CKEDITOR_SETTINGS_MODEL1', blank=True)
```

in settings.py file:

```
CKEDITOR_SETTINGS_MODEL1 = {
    'language': '{{ language }}',
    'toolbar_HTMLField': [
    {'name': 'basicstyles', 'items': ['Bold', 'Italic', 'Underline', 'Strike', 'Subscript', 'Superscript', '-', 'RemoveFormat']},
        {'name': 'colors', 'items': ['TextColor', 'BGColor']},
        {'name': 'paragraph', 'items': ['NumberedList', 'BulletedList', 'Outdent', 'Indent', 'Blockquote', 'JustifyLeft', 'JustifyCenter', 'JustifyRight',
                    'JustifyBlock', '-', 'BidiLtr', 'BidiRtl', 'Language']},
        {'name': 'clipboard', 'items': ['Paste', 'Undo', 'Redo']},
        {'name': 'tools', 'items': ['Maximize']},
        {'name': 'styles', 'items': ['Styles', 'Format', 'Font', 'FontSize', 'Scayt']},
        {'name': 'document', 'items': ['Preview', 'Print']},
        {'name': 'editing', 'items': ['Find', 'Replace', 'SelectAll']},
        {'name': 'links', 'items': ['Link', 'Unlink', 'Table', 'SpecialChar', 'Smiley']},
    ],
    'height': '777px',
    'width': '759px',
    'scayat_slang': ['en_US, en_GB, pt_BR, da_DK, nl_NL, en_CA, fi_FI, fr_FR, fr_CA, de_DE, el_GR, it_IT, nb_NO, pt_PT, es_ES, uk_UK'],
    'removePlugins': 'elementspath',
    'extraPlugins': ','.join(['div', 'clipboard', 'dialog', 'scayt',]), 
}
```

You can change this size, buttons, other

Comment: If You have image uploader plugin just add to toolbar